# Avoiding Duplicate item in loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I wrote a query to show related posts in Wordpress, 
A brief explanation: 
First it checks what categories current post belongs to,
then puts "slug" name of that categories inside an array ("$cats")
Then using foreach, I query the posts with same taxonomies.
This code works great except for when current post belongs to more than one category and there is another post which belongs to these categories too, in this situation the other post gets displayed twice or even more depending on how many categories they share,

**So the question is, How do I check if a post is repeating and how to prevent it?**
Code:

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $currentid, 'taxonomy' );
$cats = array_map(function($a){ return $a->slug; }, $terms);

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $args=array(
  'taxonomy' => $cat ,
  'post_type' => 'apps',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
);
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    if($currentid !== get_the_ID()){ 


  ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){
    $appfetured      = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ));
    $appfeturedimage = $appfetured[0];
    }else{
    $appfeturedimage = '../img/defaultappicon.png';
    }
    ?>
    <img class="appfeatured" src="<?php echo $appfeturedimage; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <?php
    }
   endwhile;

wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}//end foreach
?>
```

Comment: Ideally, you would construct a query which searches for matches on _all_ the categories at once, and only returns the unique posts. However, having kept a safe distance from wordpress I don't know whether `'taxonomy' => $cats` is valid in `WP_Query` arguments, though I do imagine it could be translated to a nice `IN()` clause...

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is get all of the posts in all of the categories for the current post try this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'cat'            => wp_get_post_categories($currentid),
        'post_type'      => 'apps',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    );

    new WP_Query($args);
```

It's been a while since I've used Wordpress so I don't know if there's a difference between the categories and the taxonomies so you can try this:

```
<?php
    terms = get_the_terms( $currentid, 'taxonomy' );
    $cats = array_map(function($a){ return $a->slug; }, $terms);

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => $cats,
        'post_type' => 'apps',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
    );

    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```